# BitmapSource binding memory leak

Tags: wpf

The problem is the same with BitmapImage but for demonstration let's use BitmapSource. Basically if I'm showing a fairly large image in a view and I set the bound object to null when I'm done with it the image memory does not get reclaimed no matter how long you wait. The full code to reproduce the problem:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestBitmapSource.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBitmapSource"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=ReloadCommand}">Load</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=ReleaseCommand}">Release</Button>
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyImage}"></Image>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace TestBitmapSource
{
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BitmapSource myImage;
    public BitmapSource MyImage
    {
        get { return myImage; }
        set { myImage = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "") 
    { 
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private ICommand _reloadCommand;
    public ICommand ReloadCommand 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _reloadCommand ?? (_reloadCommand = new CommandHandler(() => Reload(), true)); 
        } 
    }
    private ICommand _releaseCommand;
    public ICommand ReleaseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _releaseCommand ?? (_releaseCommand = new CommandHandler(() => Release(), true));
        }
    }


    Random random = new Random();
    public void Reload()
    {
        int width = 6000;
        int height = 6000;
        int b = random.Next();
        int g = random.Next();
        int r = random.Next();
        unsafe
        {
            byte* pixels = (byte*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(width * height * 3);
            for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
            {
                pixels[i * 3] = (byte)b;
                pixels[i * 3 + 1] = (byte)g;
                pixels[i * 3 + 2] = (byte)r;
            }
            MyImage = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null, (IntPtr)pixels, width * height * 3, width * 3);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)pixels);
            MyImage.Freeze();
        }
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        MyImage = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyImage = null;
    }
}

public class CommandHandler : ICommand 
{ 
    private Action _action; private bool _canExecute; 
    public CommandHandler(Action action, bool canExecute) { _action = action; _canExecute = canExecute; } 
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return _canExecute; } 
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged; 
    public void Execute(object parameter) { _action(); } 
}
}
```

To reproduce the problem, click the Load button (which will create the image with BitmapSource.Create) and then the Release button which attempts to release the image and collect unused memory. However, the process monitor shows that the 250MB of memory is still in use, and I know that the MyImage object is still alive if I tag it with an Object ID in Visual Studio.

Two things I've found so far:

1) If I don't bind to the image in the view, everything is fine and the image object disappears immediately.

2) If you click the Release button a second time, the tagged object suddenly disappears and the memory is reclaimed.

So clearly, the act of binding creates some reference somewhere that is not released when the image object is set to null in the view model. I wanted to check if I'm missing something obvious before I get into a memory profiler.

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is that your `ImageSource` is in your ViewModel, when it NEEDS TO BE IN YOUR VIEW. Look up the class hierarchy, it inherits from `DependencyObject`. If you need to write to your `ImageSource` you can use MVPVM and have your presenter write to a [writeablebitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) from your presenter. Finally I am not sure you understand `GC.Collect()` either.

Comment: @Aron That's actually no problem at all. In WPF it is very common to have DependencyObject-derived types in view models, e.g. Brush, Drawing, Geometry, and of course also ImageSource. What you shouldn't have of course is types derived from UIElement, or anything else that would be part of a visual tree.

Comment: @Clemens `DependencyObject` is a `DispatcherObject` which for all intents and purposes is a STA class, and requires the `Dispatcher` (UI) thread to access it. If that isn't a UI element, then I don't know what is. Same for Brush, Drawing etc, as they need to live on the Graphics Card.

Comment: @Aron Sure, but we're talking about a *view model*, which is accessed (and typically also instantiated) by a view. All that is already done in the UI thread, and the Dispatcher property of instances of these types is set during their construction, in the UI thread. No problem at all.

Comment: @Clemens Unless you were thinking about automating your testing of your ViewModel.

Comment: After some memory profiling it turns out the culprit is a System.Windows.Media.RenderData object that somehow still holds a strong reference to the BitmapSource after executing Release. A possibly related RenderData bug [has been filed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/851004/renderdata-can-be-the-source-of-memory-leaks) even though this one does not seem to be related to freezing. Invoking UpdateLayout on the image control after setting BitmapSource to null clears the reference. Not sure if there is a better workaround?